# Does apportable work with UIKit classes?

Tags: apportable

For the last 30 minutes I've been checking out Apportable and am now installing it.

After going over the docs, I can't see whether or not UIKit is supported.

Is it? If so, what is the look and feel on Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not supported in the Starter (free) version (other than some rudimentary classes). It is  supported in the Indie version and above, but it seems it is beta. See: http://www.apportable.com/pricing, where holding the mouse over "Advanded Frameworks" says it supports UIKit.

Comment: UIKit support is indeed in beta (no alpha support for controls is annoying) but there is a new UIKit implementation on its way. No ETA though but i am waiting for it ;)

Comment: As of the current date, the [Apportable pricing page](http://www.apportable.com/pricing) shows UIKit (limited) as being part of the Core Frameworks, and being available in the Starter (free) plan. It is still very beta. I haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: "Advanced Frameworks" is no longer a row in the pricing table

Comment: If you hover over "Core Frameworks", it now says "UIKit (limited)". There's a forum discussion here: http://forum.apportable.com/t/problems-with-uitableview-very-slow-performance/576 where an engineer writes "The UIKit implementation in the current SDK is very limited and runs without hardware acceleration. I would avoid UIKit in your game if possible."